# How to open .mrc files

Tags: software-recommendation

I've just downloaded some .mrc files. But I couldn't find the right application to open it. I'm using Ubuntu 11.10 What application should I have to open them?

Comment: Depends on what the files are. [This site](http://file-types.cryer.info/m/mrc/index.htm) lists three file types which have the extension `.mrc`.

Comment: Edelweiss, Can you come back and either accept an answer or answer your own question and accept that answer? Were you able to resolve this issue?

Answer (score -1):

I would try opening a file in gedit or another plain text editor.

Assuming these are very small files (2 kilobytes or smaller), they are usually mIRC script files, for use with the Windows IRC client of the same name.